# PHP / Github Actions workflows: how to provide secrets in $_ENV

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to use Encrypted secrets from Github to phpunit.

I created some encrypted Secrets in Github, and I tested that in my workflow file :

```
- name: Execute tests
  env:
    TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
    TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET }}
    TWITTER_ACCOUNT_ID: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_ACCOUNT_ID }}
    TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN }}
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY }}
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET }}
  run: vendor/bin/phpunit
```

But in my Test file, a simple `var_dump($_ENV)` is empty (`array(0) { }`), and my tests don't work.

What is missing ?

Best regards.

Screenshot from Github:
[image: Screenshot from Github]

Comment: to narrow down the problem, I would suggest trying A) echo an env variable directly, like so `run: echo ${{ env.TWITTER_ACCOUNT_ID }}` to make sure they're really set. If they are, try running php directly , like so: `run: php -r 'var_dump($_ENV)'`

Comment: This is not specific to PHP or PHPUnit, but rather a general GitHub Actions topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

after various tests I realized that `$_ENV` is not the same as `getenv()`.

So something like that works:

```
foreach (getenv() as $settingKey => $settingValue) {
    if (strpos($settingKey, 'TWITTER_') === 0) {
        ...
    }
}
```